# Can 'RSS of parent process + USS of child process' be total memory usage?

Tags: memory

I need to know the total memory usage of a process famaily in Linux.
While doing this, I want to know how much memory the childs uses newly.

In this situation, is it correct to check RSS of the parent and USS of the childs?